# What does splat operator between two integers mean?

Tags: php

What does splat operator between two integers mean?

As far as I know, the splat operator is used for passing the parameter on function. [Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

An example :

```
<?php
function fx(...$a) {
 print_r($a);
}
fx(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // array 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

But what does it mean when the splat operator is between two integers like this?

```
<?php
echo 1...3; // Why is the output 10.3?
echo PHP_EOL;

echo 12...100; // Why is the output 120.1?
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: You mean a `variadic`  http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`...`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) operator works only for unpacking traversable objects.

Your example uses [`.`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#language.operators.string) operator to concatenate two numbers interpreted as strings.

The following are equivalent:

```
echo 1...3;         // interpreted as ((int) 1) . ((float) 0.3)
echo '1' . '0.3';

echo 12...100;      // interpreted as ((int) 12) . ((float) 0.1)
echo '12' . '0.1';
```